Movie about a witch who brings her sister back to life
I think I saw this movie in the late 80s.
A woman dies, and a few weeks or months later her sister, who is a witch, brings her back to life.  I recall her explaining to her sister how some unlikely astrological phenomena was required, for instance, a certain planet had to be in conjunction with the dog star (Sirius).  The girl brought back also had to find true love in a certain amount of time or she would not remain alive.  At the climax of the movie her sister pretends to be possessed by somebody to trick the antagonist into admitting something he did, thinking the spirit will reveal the locaiton of some valuable treasure.

Hello Again is the one that came to my mind
Plot Summary:

Long Island housewife Lucy Chadman in the midst of a tarot card
  reading by her occult sister, Zelda. Just as Zelda exclaims something
  is going to happen, Lucy begins to choke to death on a South Korean
  Chicken Ball. The film shows the difficulty of Lucy's loved ones,
  including Zelda, had in coping with her death. But the grief turns to
  excitement when Zelda receives a book of spells called The Wisdom of
  Catagonia. Within the book Zelda finds a spell that requires perfect
  astronomical timing—the moon, the earth, and the dog star must form a
  perfect isosceles triangle. Zelda performs the spell and Lucy appears.
  ...
  Zelda confides in the doctor that if Lucy does not find love by
  the next full moon, she will have to go back to the spirit world.
  ...


Why you thinks that, explanation is the key of good answers.

That's it!  But a longer explanation would have been nice. :-)

I took the liberty of adding a partial summary that matches up with your question.

I apologize for not giving a longer answer. Still new to the site.
